# shellscript to read log files of a docker containerised application on a remote VM is not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, ssh

I have an application running on VM 100.111.**.*** . I can use the below commands to connect to the VM and get into the docker bash to read the log file which are available at path `/logs/MTServices/applogs/application.log`.
Steps are :

1. Do ssh to VM
   `ssh -i ~/.ssh/dev_rsa infy@100.111.**.***`
   [image]

[image]

2. Once connected, run the docker command `sudo docker exec -it MTWLS bash`
   [image]
3. Now I am in the docker bash and I can use the command to change the directory to read the logs.
   [image]

So far so good. Now When I create a shell script for the above commands and I run it, it doesn't seem to work. Below the is script.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "starting"
VM_Host="100.111.**.***" 
echo $VM_Host
pattern="Performing asynchronous operation for tenant"
echo $pattern
WLSType="MTWLS"
echo $WLSType

echo "running ssh"
ssh -i ~/.ssh/devus1_rsa opc@${VM_Host}
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
then
    echo "last command was success"
    sudo docker exec -it ${WLSType} bash
    echo $(pwd)
fi
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
then
    cd /logs/ETLServices/applogs
    echo $(pwd)
fi
grep -s "$pattern" application_structured.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot try it myself, but I think the problem is here

```
sudo docker exec -it ${WLSType} bash
```

Right there you're starting a new process, interactive, and pass the control to it: I think that the following lines of your script will be executed only after you close the docker process

Comment: I need to read the logs from docker bash only. when I run ```sudo docker exec -it MTWLS bash```  it prompts a different user on the same VM. then I can navigate to the dir where logs are